# Two way data binding between an input field to an object property of type number results in a string value

Tags: angularjs, typescript

If I have an object Customer in Typescript (skeletal example):

```
var Customer: ICustomer = <ICustomer>{};
...
interface ICustomer {
orderAmount: number;
}
```

and in html:

```
<input ng-model="vm.Customer.orderAmount"... >
```

and the user types a number in the input field, the orderAmount contains a string instead of a number. Is this normal behavior? I was expecting a number as I was expecting TypeScript to cast the value to a number because of the number type. Looks like I still have to parse the value if I want to do arithmetic operations to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your input to type="number", that should make it so that your model is a number and not a string.

```
    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value">
```

Note that your model must always be a number to prevent an error from being thrown if you set the input element to type="number"